# Javascript and CSS onclick Div Swap

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am new to both Javascript and designing for Facebook. I am using Shortstack to create custom tabs and have created a 3 panel sub-tab application using the service. In the 3rd panel, I have 19 div's holding information. By default, I use CSS to hide these DIVs (display:none;) and have a series of links at the top of the panel that change the visibility of each DIV onclick. Only the active onclick content is visible at any time.

The tab functions properly in Firefox, Chrome, and even Safari on the Mac, but fails in all browsers on the PC, and fails differently. In IE, immediately after the swap happens an error message pops up which mentions the publisher not allowing the action in an iFrame. In Firefox the tab just goes blank with no error message.

My script is below. As I stated, I am new to coding for Facebook and working with Javascript as I am a designer and not a programmer, but am eager to learn.

Thank you in advance for your thoughts and ideas.

```
    function showhide(layer_ref) {
        var thisDiv;
        // check to see if any DIVs are currently showing
        var divlist = ["div1","div2","div3","div4","div5","div6","div7","div8","div9","div10","div11","div12","div13","div14","div15","div16","div17","div18","div19"];
        // loop through the list of DIVs in "divlist"
        for (x = 0; x < divlist.length; x++) {
            thisDiv = document.getElementById(divlist[x]);
            // if the DIV is showing, hide it
            if (thisDiv.style.display == "block") {
                thisDiv.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        // show the appropriate DIV
        thisDiv = document.getElementById(layer_ref);
        thisDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change the things in iframe that could be a problem if the iframe is loaded from different domain. It is basically security rule - you don't want to allow rogue code to change/read/write things on the page other than it's own.

To answer your question better we need to know where is changing javascript is located and what it tries to change (are those two things loaded from the same domain or not).

The script itself looks ok to me.